# CUDA concurrent kernel execution with multiple kernels per stream

Tags: concurrency, cuda

Using different streams for CUDA kernels makes concurrent kernel execution possible. Therefore `n` kernels on `n` streams could theoretically run concurrently if the they are fitting into the hardware, right?

Now I'm facing the following problem: There are not `n` distinct kernels but `n*m` where `m` kernels need to be executed in order. For instance `n=2` and `m=3` would lead to the following execution scheme with streams:

```
Stream 1: <<<Kernel 0.1>>> <<<Kernel 1.1>>> <<<Kernel 2.1>>>
Stream 2: <<<Kernel 0.2>>> <<<Kernel 1.2>>> <<<Kernel 2.2>>>
```

My naive assumption is that the kernels x.0 and y.1 should execute concurrently (from a theoretic point of view) or at least not consecutively (from a practical point of view). But my measurements are showing me that this is not the case and it seems that consecutive execution is performed (i. e. K0.0, K1.0, K2.0, K0.1, K1.1, K2.1). The kernels itself are very small, so concurrent execution should not be a problem.

Now my approach would be to accomplish a kind of dispatching for making sure that the kernels are en-queued in an interleaved style into the scheduler on the GPU. But when dealing with a large number of streams / kernels this could do more harm than good.

Alright, coming straight to the point: What would be an appropriate (or at least different) approach to solve this situation?

**Edit:** Measurements are done by using CUDA events. I've measured the time that is needed to fully solve the computation, i. e. the GPU has to compute all `n * m` kernels. The assumption is: On fully concurrent kernel execution the execution time is roughly (ideally) `1/n` times of the time that is needed to execute all kernels in order, whereby it must be possible that two or more kernels can be executed concurrently. I'm ensuring this by only using two distinct streams right now.

I can measure a clear difference regarding execution times between using the streams as described and dispatching kernels interleaved, i. e.:

```
Loop: i = 0 to m
    EnqueueKernel(Kernel i.1, Stream 1)
    EnqueueKernel(Kernel i.2, Stream 2)
```

versus

```
Loop: i = 1 to n
    Loop: j = 0 to m
        EnqueueKernel(Kernel j.i, Stream i)
```

The latter leads to a longer runtime.

**Edit #2:** Changed the Stream numbers to begin by 1 (instead of 0, see comments below).

**Edit #3:** Hardware is a NVIDIA Tesla M2090 (i. e. Fermi, compute capability 2.0)

Comment: You probably need to use some stream synchronization primitives to enforce the execution order you need. But could you maybe expand a little on how you did your measurements in your question, and could you also confirm that when you write "Stream 0", you don't literally mean CUDA stream 0 ?

Comment: I clarified the measurement (at least i hope so). With streams I'm meaning instances of `cudaStream_t` as described in [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/DevZone/docs/html/C/doc/CUDA_C_Programming_Guide.pdf), section 3.2.5 (Asynchronous Concurrent Execution).

Comment: Perhaps you misunderstood what I was asking -- I mean is one of your streams CUDA stream 0, because stream 0 (the default stream) is synchronous.

Comment: I'll have to check this, sorry for not providing a more satisfying answer instantly. I'd like to ask you to provide me a reference to the source for this statement (maybe I've overseen this in the documentation).

Comment: Section 3.2.5.5.2 of the Programming guide "Default Stream".

Comment: Thanks for the reference. No, I'm not using Stream 0 anywhere (also changed the question to use Streams beginning by 1).

Comment: Had to ask, are you using a fermi+ gpu ?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning, made an edit.

Comment: @macs, the concurrent execution also depends on the resources you are using (blocks * threads, shared memory * blocks etc). Can you try using a smaller problem size to see if streams are faster than serial implementation for your algorithm ?

Comment: @Pavan right, but in my opinion the used resources are not that large. However, I've programmed a small example which resembles the problem within the question, but unfortunately the behavior is **not** the same, i. e. the kernels are executed concurrently. So I assume that there is another problem within my original code, which I'll have to investigate further.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Fermi (aka Compute Capability 2.0) hardware it is best to interleave kernel launches to multiple streams rather than to launch all kernels to one stream, then the next stream, etc.  This is because the hardware can immediately launch kernels to different streams if there are sufficient resources, whereas if subsequent launches are to the same stream there is often delay introduced, reducing concurrency.  This is the reason that your first approach performs better, and this approach is the one you should choose.

Enabling profiling can also disable concurrency on Fermi, so be careful with that.  Also, be careful about using CUDA events during your launch loop, as these can interfere -- best to time the whole loop using events as you are doing, for example.

Comment: Can you give me a source where this knowledge (within the first paragraph, not the second) comes from?

Comment: There is information in Section 3 of the CUDA 4.1 Programming Guide.  However after reading it I see that it does not explicitly say "interleave kernel launches".  I got the information from my colleagues in the NVIDIA CUDA software team.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I'm going to revisit my code and provide more informations / updates if possible.

Comment: Ok, according to this information I've introduced interleaving and this solves the issue. However it would be nice if the CUDA Programming Guide would address this issue.

Comment: The "Streams and Concurrency Webinar" has some very useful information on using streams properly (http://developer.download.nvidia.com/CUDA/training/StreamsAndConcurrencyWebinar.pdf).  The technical details of dispatch are on slide 15, followed by a series of example slides.