# How to combine OpenMP with CUDA appropriately

Tags: cuda, openmp

I have tried to combine my CUDA code with OpenMP recently but some problems occur. My CUDA-OpenMP code is written as

```
    int main (void)
    {
       cudaGetDeviceCount(&gpuNum);

       //declare variables
       float *data_h; *data_d[gpuNum];
       data_h = (float*)malloc(Mem);
       ....
       ....
       omp_set_num_threads(gpuNum); 
       #pragma omp parallel
       {
         int cpuid = omp_get_thread_num();
         cudaSetDevice(cpuid);

         cudaMalloc((void**)&data_d[cpuid], Mem );

         cudaMemcpy( data_d[cpuid], data_h, Mem, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
         kernel<<< gpu_block, gpu_thread >>>();
         cudaMemcpy( data_h, data_d[cpuid], Mem, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
       }
       printf("end of parallel\n");
       //post process
     }
```

The problem is that sometimes when I run this code, everything is going well, but sometimes it will stop and the "end of parallel" sentence will not be printed out. This situation happens randomly and can anybody tell me what might be the reason for this?

Comment: I am not sure about the reason, but my guess is each thread is copying the final result into "data_h" (after the kernel has completed). It might involve some locking. May be try allocating memory for each thread and copying the final result. Check whether even that program hangs.

Comment: Please check the return values of all API calls (see http://stackoverflow.com/tags/cuda/info for tips on asking questions).

Answer (score 2):

I want to provide some possibilities of failures:

In the parallel region imagine that when the first two lines are executed the active thread is switched with another one,

```
#pragma omp parallel{
  int cpuid = omp_get_thread_num();
  cudaSetDevice(cpuid);
  ...
}
```

then another thread will call the set device function and selected device will be changed.

While the memcopy operations are blocking the kernel call is not. So, if the threads are switched after the kernel call, while one kernel call is not completed another kernel call will be issued. To execute concurrent kernels you need to use "**streams**". Take a look at

[CUDA concurrent kernel execution with multiple kernels per stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9311015/cuda-concurrent-kernel-execution-with-multiple-kernels-per-stream)

Comment: This speculation is not quite correct. cudaSetDevice() is host thread-safe. runtime api manual: ``This call may be made from any host thread, to any device, and at any time.''

Comment: As far as I see, there is a race condition in here. While one thread sets the device to be 0, the other one sets it to 1 and so on..

Comment: Multiple host threads calling cudaSetDevice does not result in a race condition. If you do not believe the runtime  API manual, check the driver API counterpart. It clearly says cuCtxCreate, cuCtxPopCurrent and cuCtxPushCurrent are associated with the calling CPU thread, which implies the context-related variables are thread-local. OP's problem is more likely caused by a failed kernel call.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve best performance I suggest you not to use OpenMP to run CUDA. I know from my experience, that creating threds by OpenMP is not costless and it takes some time. During creating threads you will be able to run more gpu kernels on many devices.

As mentioned @phoad you can use streams if your datasets are independent. You can find a lot of examples on the web.

The other possibility is re-designing your kernel. One kernel can make the same work and return array as result.